# How to make a simple systemd minecraft server startup service

Tags: server, 18.04, java, systemd, minecraft

So I have spent around a month searching online and figuring out how to start a vanilla Minecraft server as soon ubuntu server boots, but I couldn't make it work.

Using Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS on Pentium G4560 with Intel 545s 512GB SSD with 8GB of RAM (its a physical box inside my basement so if for some reason direct access is needed)

Simply I have a Minecraft server instance in `/home/petar/Minecraft` and a script that i can use manually to start it up `/home/username/petar/run.sh`, what i found out is that you need a systemd service to run it so i made: `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/vanilla-mc.service` and it goes like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=mc-vanilla-startup-service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/petar/minecraft/run.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

than i used sudo systemctl enable vanilla-mc.service
and i rebooted my server
after it booted i typed in systemctl status vanilla-mc.service and got:

```
vanilla-mc.service - mc-vanilla-startup-service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vanilla-mc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-14 17:28:06 CET; 2h 36min ago
Main PID: 969 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

WHY IT DOESN'T WORK ???

BTW here is `./run.sh` from minecraft folder:`

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xms1024M -Xmx3072M -jar server.jar -o true`
```

sorry for some reson i cant get formating to work correctly

**EDIT (After 3 years and a few collage subjects)**

I need to point out, never run scripts as root. What you should do insted is alter the service to look something like this

Note that you need to change `username` to your real username

```
[Unit]
Description=app-service

[Service]
User=username
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/home/username/appdir/run.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That way the application will run as the user who owns the assosiated files and as well help prevent any unwanted commands getting executed as root (at the moment there is a big problem effecting java apps using log4j2 for logging, one of theme is Minecraft)

Take a look at the autorestart option, very usefull for running some not so stable software (modded minecraft servers for example)

The script `run.sh` should be in the same direcotry as the application file we are trying to run (in our case `server.jar`) and it should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/username/appdir
java -jar server.jar -Xmx4G
```

Again make sure to change the `username` to your correct system user

The reason why the script did not work before for the service was caused by the missing directory directive, basicaly our service was not able to find the server application we were trying to run

Also dont forget to make the script executable by running `chmod u+x run.sh`

now you can do `sudo systemctl enable servicename` and then 'sudo systemctl start servicename'

I know that this post is old but i hope this helped somone fix there issues

Comment: Please note that ./run.sh is a working script, i use it every time manually on the server itself, tho i am running it as root every time...

Comment: Have you read https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script ?

Comment: @MatsK i wonna have a secure system, i never run scripts from github, and i alweys prefere to do it myself, i woud never in my life run a script from github again, i had bad experience with it, i am running a css  game server and i used a startup script from github and it turnes out i used my server to be member of bot net, i was called from my ISP to check it, i was so pissed...

Comment: That is your prerogative, and I agree with your security perspective, you should aways inspect the source. But as the link I provided states, **Warning** 
Since this is a wiki and anyone may modify any page at any time, it is suggested that you do not actually use this script but instead simply use it as a guideline for writing your own.

Comment: Does your script have executable permission?

Comment: I will be honest with you, that was a long time ago, but what i can see and remember yes it was executable but i missed to set the directry frist time i did this. I edited the post because a friend of mine was trying to do the same as i did 3 years ago and accidentaly got to my post somehow, i got that working a while back but never updated it here, since he reminded me i just sat down and edited for future refenrece if somone ever needed it